# How can I install PHP and MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, php, python

How can I install PHP with mod_python and MySQL on Ubuntu 9 64bit if I have *already* Apache 2 installed?

Comment: FWIW, be very careful running PHP and mod_python within same Apache. Read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ apt-get install php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-python
```